# How to get the number of particular child elements for each matched element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the number of matched child elements for each matched parent element?
HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   Today I've eaten <mark>potatoes</mark>
</div>
<div class="parent"> 
   Yesterday I <mark>jumped</mark> and <mark>educated</mark> myself.
</div>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
var context = $(".parent");
var amountOfMarksInside = context.each().has("mark").children("mark").length;
```

The idea is to get the number of marks inside a particular parent while looping through all parents of a "parent" class. How can I do it? Both JS and jQuery solutions are appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question

Answer (score 0):

To get the specific parent you need to attach an event handler to it in order to have a reference you can use to select the child `mark` elements. In the example below I used `click`, but any event will work.

```js
$('.parent').on('click', e => {
  let numMarks = $(e.currentTarget).children('mark').length;
  console.log(numMarks);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  Today I've eaten <mark>potatoes</mark>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Yesterday I <mark>jumped</mark> and <mark>educated</mark> myself.
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the count for all `.parent` elements you could use a loop. `map()` does this implicitly:

```js
let numMarks = $('.parent').map((i, el) => $(el).children('mark').length).get();
console.log(numMarks);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  Today I've eaten <mark>potatoes</mark>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Yesterday I <mark>jumped</mark> and <mark>educated</mark> myself.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using vanilla JS, no need of Jquery. Just get all the mark tags inside parent class like this.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.parent mark').length)
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   Today I've eaten <mark>potatoes</mark>
</div>
<div class="parent"> 
   Yesterday I <mark>jumped</mark> and <mark>educated</mark> myself.
</div>
```

Comment: I am aware of this. But I need to do so while looping through over a 100 .parent divs, and this is where I need help.

Comment: I'm still not getting your point, `querySelectorAll('.parent mark')` will check through all .parent divs which have `mark` tag inside of it

Comment: Ok, let me give more detail. I need to hide all divs that don't have an exact amount of child mark elements.